# I just saved over a cpp file in xcode with a blank file. Is there any way to recover the previously saved version?

Tags: xcode

I just saved over a cpp file from xcode with a blank cpp file.  Is there in way to recover the previously saved version? The system I am using is Mac OS X Version 10.7.5.

Comment: No Time Machine, no source code repository like Git or SVN?

Comment: No Time Machine, I am not sure about Git or SVN. I just recently started using xcode.

Comment: I have found where there are Git files but I am not sure where to find SVN. I did not see any related Git files.

Comment: You're hosed.  You really owe it to yourself to attach a second hard drive and enable Time Machine.